# Make sure you typed the name correctly. and then try again. After using unattend.xml on when sysprep

Tags: windows, xml, sysprep, answerfile

After using `unattend.xml` on when Sysprep I'm using VMware workstation to create Windows 8.1 Pro image (install.wim) and using untattend.xml to copy profile settings to all new users.

I make installation after this and I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to go audit mode and add updates and soft + copy unattend.xml and wimscript.ini to `C:\windows\system32\sysprep` folder. After this use sysprep command:

```
sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown /unattend:C:\windows\system32\sysprep\unattend.xml
```

Then startup system and go to dism and make successfully image: But when I make new installation with this image and go to start search some settings I can't open it and get this [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3iHo.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"
                    processorArchitecture="amd64"
                    publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                    language="neutral"
                    versionScope="nonSxS"
                    xmlns:wcm="schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
 <settings pass="specialize">
       <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of submitting unformatted unreadable commentary with what could be relevant information.

Comment: @T15K6 - Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting). See my edit as done for you.

Comment: thanks for edit i cant paste correctly code

Comment: i just cant understand whats wrong with unattend.xml when i use this  and making install.wim after this i install windows with this install.wim and i get that error when i trying to open